# WPF- Bind list to listview

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, binding

I'm creating a wpf application and capturing images from my usb webcam. What I have tried is store all captured images in a `List` and show them in a `Listview`

```
public List<BitmapImage> listOfCapturedImages = new List<BitmapImage>();

private void addNewImageButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            CameraWindow cw = new CameraWindow(this);
            cw.newlyCapturedImage += (BitmapImage newImage) =>
            {
                listOfCapturedImages.Add(newImage);
                newlyAddedImage.Source = newImage;
            };
            cw.Show();
        }
```

**XAML:**

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding listOfCapturedImages}" Height="345" Margin="577,10,10,0" VerticalAlignment="Top">            
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="GridViewColumnHeader">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                        </Style>
                    </GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>
                    <GridViewColumn x:Name="previewImagesColumn">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                <Button x:Name="firstImageOflistViewButton" Content="{Binding listOfCapturedImages}" Height="50">
                                    <Button.Template>
                                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                                            <ContentPresenter/>
                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                    </Button.Template>
                                </Button>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
```

Could someone help me please, what I'm missing?

Answer (score 6):

Thanks a lot guys, I have fixed my problem with your helps. I want to share my working code just for someone else who may have the same problem with me. Here is the working code:

```
public ObservableCollection<BitmapImage> listOfCapturedImages { get; } = 
   new ObservableCollection<BitmapImage>();

private void addNewImageButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            CameraWindow cw = new CameraWindow(this);
            cw.newlyCapturedImage += (BitmapImage newImage) =>
            {
                listOfCapturedImages.Add(newImage);
                newlyAddedImage.Source = newImage;
            };
            cw.Show();
        }
```

I also have added `this.DataContext = this;`.

```
public Test(Window window)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = this;          
        }
```

And finally **XAML:**

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding listOfCapturedImages}" Height="345" Margin="577,10,10,0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <UniformGrid Columns="1"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Image Source="{Binding}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Answer (score 3):

You are binding to field not a property.

Change:

```
public List<BitmapImage> listOfCapturedImages = new List<BitmapImage>();
```

to

```
public ObservableCollection<BitmapImage> ListOfCapturedImages {get;} = new ObservableCollection<BitmapImage>();
```

`ObservableCollection` is the collection that will notify of changing its contents and the binding will update after you add items to it. `List` will not do that.

Also include some `Image` displaying item:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfCapturedImages}" >
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Source="{Binding}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Good answer bar your point about image control lacks any context

Answer (score 3):

Couple of problems

1. Use `ObservableCollection` instead of `List`. `List` do not notify View to update itself when an item is added to it. `ObservableCollection` does that.
2. `listOfCapturedImages` is a Field. Even if you set is to `public`, it cannot be used to bind in WPF. Because Field are invisible to `XAML`, whereas Properties are visible. So do this

   ```
   public ObservableCollection<BitmapImage> listOfCapturedImages { get; } = 
      new ObservableCollection<BitmapImage>();
   ```

Comment: How about the Xaml? Sould I make changes there as well?

Comment: Tadej has covered the Xaml issues, this covers the Code behind issues together they cover everything

Answer (score 2):

You should have `Image` control in your `DataTemplate`. This is what i am using:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding listOfCapturedImages}" >
     <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid Columns="1"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Source="{Binding}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: You've misses the issues with the binding but hit the XAML issue on the head